# Can a prisoner leave a gang? If so, How?

Tags: prison-architect

I've got a lot of gang members in my prison. I've succeeded to limit the recruitment of new members ( By isolating all lieutenants and the leaders in separate buildings), but I still have a lot of gang members.

Can they leave their gang?

Comment: Even without a leader, gang members have the annoying habit to rush to help when one of their homies is in a fight.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to force a prisoner to leave a gang, nor will they do so of their own accord.

Isolating senior gang members is a good plan, however remember that if they are actually in lockdown or solitary for too long the danger level in the prison increases dramatically.  This is explained further in the [Alpha 35 video](https://youtu.be/n18NBSRegP0).

The [wikia entry for gangs](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Gangs) suggests that you yourself can get kicked out of a gang in escape mode if you kill a fellow gang member.

Answer (score 0):

Page 23 of the game bible mentions lone gang members slowly losing allegiance, but this hasn't been implemented AFAIK.